# Proof on Open & Closed Sets

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

I just did a quick proof, and it seemed so simple that I wanted to check if it was correct.

Prove that if you have a nonempty subset, $S$, of a domain $\Omega$, and $S$ is both open and closed, then $S=\Omega$.

Assume $S\neq\Omega$, then $\Omega-S$ is nonempty. By the definition of a domain (particularly the condition that a domain has to be connected), $\Omega$ can't be split into two nonempty open sets that are disjoint. But since $S$ is open and closed, then $S$ and $\Omega-S$ are both open, and since $S\neq\Omega$, both are nonempty. However, $\Omega-S\cap S=\emptyset$, and $\Omega-S\cup S=\Omega$, which contradicts that $\Omega$ is a domain, since $\Omega-S$ and $S$ are two nonempty, open, disjoint, sets that split $\Omega$. Therefore $\Omega=S$.

I'm new to writing proofs, so if the language can be improved, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm fine with your proof - though you seem to repeat the argument

Comment: What part would you omit, to make the argument less redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're talking about openness or closedness of some set, you need to mention the underlying topological space. Your claim is not true in an arbitrary topological space. It holds only when the space is connected.

Comment: I haven't touched the topic of topology yet - this is only part of an introductory review of some Calculus topics. May I ask: can a domain exist in a disconnected topological space? It seems weird to me to think that a connected open set (domain) can exist in a topological space that isn't connected.

Comment: Well, yes. In a discrete topological space, that does happen. But since you haven't read any topology, you can leave this now and come back to it when you read topology. In real analysis, your claim in true and the proof is correct! :-)